# (IE9) jQuery Validation error cut in half vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am running into styling issues with IE9 and jQuery Validation. I have tested and it is styled correctly in Chrome and Firefox. Below is a screen capture of what I'm seeing:

[image: Strange Validation Bug]

Depending on the order of how I focus the element sometimes the top of the error message is cut off and other times it's the bottom of the error message. Inspecting the element, it seems that there is a span that is injected into the wrapping DOM element so the message is not simply hidden when it's valid. I'm being forced to develop and test with a crap laptop so maybe it has something to do with settings? I'm not sure...has anyone seen this kind of styling issue before? If so, what is the cause?

Here's is the markup for this field:

```html
<div class="control-group col-md-6"><span title="Required" class="text-danger glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
  <label class="control-label" for="OperatorName">Operator Name</label><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="OperatorName" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span class="" for="OperatorName">The Operator Name field is required.</span></span>
  <div class="controls">
    <input aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Operator Name must be a string with a maximum length of 255." data-val-length-max="255" data-val-required="The Operator Name field is required."
    id="OperatorName" maxlength="255" name="OperatorName" value="Haley Chisholm and Morris Inc" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to say without inspecting the DOM - do you have a link?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. I will update my original post with the markup.

Comment: Still hard to guess - you need to include the relevant CSS!  Make the snippet display the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Validate!! oh the sorrow.. Actually, it does do a great job. My personal grief is brought on by the unnecessary DOM elements it generates. No one needs to put a span in a span, within a span, wrapped in a span. Sorry.. To the answer!

Try giving your span span span a margin-top. It looks like your text is being cut off. Inline elements will inherit the parents box model boundaries. In good practice, you should add a min-height value to the same size as your text to help with responsiveness.

Read about inline elements here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente